# Using multiple mapped types for objects key/values. Need only one value from union?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Having some trouble trying to get the type to work correctly here.

I want to specify in an object that each top-level key is one of the strings from a union, and the value is a nested object that has keys of one of the strings from another union, and its value can be the string from the first union (kind of like a state-machine).

Eg:

```
type Status = 'idle' | 'loading' | 'error' | 'view'
type Actions = 'search' | 'search_success' | 'search_failure'

const app = {
  idle: {
    search: 'loading'
  },
  loading: {
    search_success: 'view',
    search_fail: 'error',
  },
  error: {
    search: 'loading'
  }
  view: {
    search: 'loading'
  }
}
```

My attempts to type this have been:

```
type States = { [key in Status]: { [key in Actions]: Status } };
```

Though this doesn't work. Could somebody explain how I could make use of some utility types possibly to allow the nested object key to not require ALL values from the Actions type?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I simplified your code a bit.

This definition

```
type Status = 'idle' | 'loading'
type State = { [key in Status]: any}
```

is equivalent to

```
type State = { 
  idle: any;
  loading: any;
}
```

Therefor, the following code is invalid

```
const foo: State = {
  idle: true
}
```

because it's missing the prop `loading`.

**A solution** - make the props optional

```
type Status = 'idle' | 'loading' | 'error' | 'view'
type Actions = 'search' | 'search_success' | 'search_failure'

type States = { [key in Status]?: { [key in Actions]?: Status } };

const app: States = {
  idle: {
    search: 'loading'
  },
  loading: {
    search_success: 'view',
    search_failure: 'error',
  },
  error: {
    search: 'loading'
  },
  view: {
    search: 'loading'
  }
}
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAysCGwCuBnKBeKByAlgEwBsIsoAfbAge3jxwDsBzE8rCAJzcreewDccIAdywAoUJCgBBAMbAclOmkxYUEeG2kALHirUbNAfRRJp0iChQ7V6rQYBm8HASRtiIseGhxE5jFADeUADaANYQIFD0sAjIKAC6APwAXAHBYRFRMnIK8cnRiKhQAL7FANzu0jnAUPBgYCnewL6Y-iJQkYQQKa3t7db6KVhUNPRMbcUANOPDtIzd4316tsam5iiD-EJYU71Q-bYOTi5d2Oyc3DuT42dc87v7moMzo6LtRZebgne9D0-Us2M3iIikA)

Answer (score 1):

The answer from @MoshFeu looks like it'll work fine, but as I've written this up, I'll post it to say that you can get more or less the same thing with a `Partial`:

```js
type Status = 'idle' | 'loading' | 'error' | 'view'
type Actions = 'search' | 'search_success' | 'search_failure'

type States = { [key in Status]: Partial<{ [key in Actions]: Status }> };

const app: States = {
  idle: {
    search: 'loading'
  },
  loading: {
    search_success: 'view',
    search_failure: 'error',
  },
  error: {
    search: 'loading'
  },
  view: {
    search: 'loading'
  }
};
```